# Starting Timer after Cleared in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this code, and I can't figure out how to starting the timer that's cleared at scrollTop, when is scrolledDown, I tried to use

```
$("#chat").scroll(function(){
    var tim = setInterval(function(){
    refreshChat();
},4000);
```

but didn't work, there are a way to fix it?
This is my full working code that cleared the timeout at scrollTop:

```
var tim = setInterval(function(){
    refreshChat();
},5000);
$("#chat").scrollTop(function(){
    clearTimeout(tim);
});
```

Comment: you have already cleared a timer, why not start a new one?

Comment: @gurvinder372 because I don't know how to do it, I mean, it has start at scrollBottom and I don't know how to set the scrollBottom, i tried with scroll but isn't working

Comment: Note that [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) doesn't accept a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *restart* an interval timer; once it's cleared, it's cleared. You'd have to start a *new* interval timer.

So

```
var refreshTimer = 0; // 0 is an invalid handle, useful initial value
function startRefreshTimer() {
    if (!refreshTimer) {
        refreshTimer = setInterval(refreshChat, 4000);
    }
}
function stopRefreshTimer() {
    clearInterval(refreshTimer);
    refreshTimer = 0;
}
```

Anywhere you need to stop it, call `stopRefreshTimer`. Anywhere you need to start it, call `startRefreshTimer`.

---

I didn't show clearing the timer the way you did (in a function passed to `scrollTop`) because [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) doesn't support passing a function into it (and if it did, it would probably be like `val` and `text` and such where it's used to *set a value*, not respond to an event).